# Entity Framework: why still trying to read from a removed entity in the DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird

I have a DbContext with many classes/entities targeting a Firebird database. I used to have an entity named DinnerPasses, which was declared (as all others) using Code First:

```
public class FreezedOrdersContext : DbContext
{
    public FreezedOrdersContext()
        : base("name=ConnectionString")
    {

    }

    // The deleted entity... (NOTE: THIS IS NO LONGER IN THE FILE...)
    public virtual DbSet<DinnerPass> DinnerPasses { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<FirebirdFreezedSalesOrder> FreezedSalesOrders { get; set; }
    // Other entities, removed for clarity...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        Database.SetInitializer<FreezedOrdersContext>(null);

        // Some of the lines still in the file...
        modelBuilder.Entity<FirebirdFreezedSalesOrder>().HasKey(p => new { p.ORDERTYPE, p.CUSTOMERTYPE, p.TABLEID, p.SUBORDERNUMBER });
        modelBuilder.Entity<FirebirdFreezedSalesOrder>().ToTable("FREEZEDSALESORDER");

        // NOTE: This 2 lines are NO LONGER in the file...
        modelBuilder.Entity<DinnerPass>().HasKey(p => p.NUMBER);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DinnerPass>().ToTable("GENERALINFO");
    }
}
```

The DinnerPasses entity was deleted. Now, reading any of the other entities goes fine, but when I try to save some other entities into the database `db.SaveChanges();`, I get the following exception:

"Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -204 Table unknown DinnerPasses At line 6, column 8"
System.Exception {FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException}

So, I guess that EF created some model file somewhere that allows it "remember" that entity (and since the line `modelBuilder.Entity<DinnerPass>().ToTable("GENERALINFO");` is no longer part of the file, it is trying to get the DinnerPass entity from a table of the same name).

How can I fix this? Where are the model files for this? They are certainly not found anywhere in my project folder...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out what happened:

I removed the DinnerPasses entity and replaced it with a new entity called GeneralInfo that was more appropriate (it gets more info from the table, instead of my initial needs that was the Dinner Pass information within that table).

Here is the issue: When I created the new GeneralInfo class, I copied a **property** from the old DinnerPass class (called FormattedDinnerPasses) into the new GeneralInfo class/entity. When I changed that property to a method, it no longer tried to access the "DinnerPasses" table.

So, I think the problem was having a property that didn't have a backing variable (the property just did a bunch of calculations and returned a list of formatted items). Maybe you can have one but need to give it an attribute indicating that it must be ignored when Entity Framework is binding to the table...

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `DbSet` and the entity class from your context entirely (including references from other entities!). If you don't specify any additional metadata, then Entity Framework will assume a tablename derived from the entity classname.